# Cocoapods how to find out the latest available version of a pod?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

How can I out the latest available version of a specified pod? For example, FirebaseRemoteConfig?

Comment: FireBase is available for Swift Package Manager. It's incomprehensible that so many people are still struggling with tedious CocoaPods

Comment: React Native does not use Swift Package Manager

Answer (score -2):

You can run the command `pod search PodName` in the terminal and it will list all of the available versions in descending order. The latest version will appear first.

`pod search FirebaseRemoteConfig` presently shows `10.3.0` as the latest.